# How to append a string or value to an existing column in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['keyword_submit']) === false && empty($errors) === true)
{
$data_keyword = array(
'keywords'=> $_POST['keywords']
);  
data_keyword($data_keyword);
header('Location: keyword.php');
exit(); 
}
?>
<form method="post" id="mainformkey">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px;">
<table id="keyword_table" width="100%" border="1" >
<tr>
<th width="60%">
Keywords
</th>
<th  width="10%">
Keyword ID
</th>
<th  width="9%">
Words
</th>
</tr>
<?php
$keyword_sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keyword");
while($row_keyword_sql1 = mysql_fetch_array($keyword_sql1)){
$id1 = $row_keyword_sql1[id];
}
if(isset($_POST[keyword_submit_add])){
$values_keyword = $_POST['keywords_extra'];
$ds = mysql_query("UPDATE keyword SET keywords = CONCAT(keywords,$values_keyword) WHERE id = '$id1'");  
}
$keyword_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE user_id='$session_user_id'");
while($row_keyword_sql = mysql_fetch_array($keyword_sql)){
$id = $row_keyword_sql[id];
$get_keyword = $row_keyword_sql[keywords];
?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $get_keyword;
?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<?php echo '@key-0'.$id;?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<form id="addnew" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keywords_extra">
<input type="submit" name="keyword_submit_add" value="Add keyword">
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background: #EDEDED; padding: 5px;">
<input type="text"  name="keywords">
<input  type="submit" name="keyword_submit" value="Main Keyword">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
function data_keyword($data_keyword)
{
array_walk($data_keyword, 'array_sanitize');
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($data_keyword)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $data_keyword) . '\'';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `keyword` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
?>
```

Here there are two submit buttons 1. First submit button: User can enter one keyword and submit (Name: Main keyword). 2. Second submit button: Second they can enter the keywords to a specific row which may append by a comma separated.

I already tried that using CONCAT in mysql but only comma is getting appending and that too in the all the rows, but i need in specific row according to the id.

Comment: try using CONCAT(keywords,',',$values_keyword)

Comment: But problem with posting the values bro, it is not getting the posted value, that is the problem.

Comment: your "keywords_extra" text field is in while loop, so change its name to "keywords_extra[]" and then try posting your form

Comment: That too i tried bro not working.

Comment: Now its inserting as array array...

Comment: Bro if it is a new entry then comma is in front how to remove that?

Comment: use trim($str,",") function

Answer (score 0):

Use [concat_ws](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead of concat, so that you can pass in the separator of your choice.

Try:

```
$ds = mysql_query("UPDATE keyword SET keywords = CONCAT_WS(' ', keywords, $values_keyword) WHERE id = '$id1'");
```

The other problem that you mention is related to your access of `id` from `$row_keyword_sql1` array.  Note that array indexes need to be within quotes if they are not variable and in this case it definitely is not a variable i.e. `$id`. Also, I think that you want to execute this query for each id's in your `$row_keyword_sql1` instead of just for the last one.

Try:

```
while($row_keyword_sql1 = mysql_fetch_array($keyword_sql1)){
  $id1 = $row_keyword_sql1['id'];

  if(isset($_POST['keyword_submit_add'])){ // Updated to use index in quotes.
    $values_keyword = $_POST['keywords_extra'];
    $ds = mysql_query("UPDATE keyword SET keywords = CONCAT_WS(' ', keywords,$values_keyword) WHERE id = '$id1'");  
  }
}
```

**Update:**

Replace the following lines:

```
$id1 = $row_keyword_sql1[id];
...
if(isset($_POST[keyword_submit_add])){ 
...
$get_keyword = $row_keyword_sql[keywords];
```

with:

```
$id1 = $row_keyword_sql1['id'];
...
if(isset($_POST['keyword_submit_add'])){ 
...
$get_keyword = $row_keyword_sql['keywords'];
```

You probably are already aware that `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and it's better to make the switch to either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) early.  Also keep in mind that sending `post`ed values directly to database is vulnerable to SQL Injection, you should at least call  `mysql_real_escape_string` on them, e.g. `$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keywords'])`

Comment: I tried that too bro, but it is appending only the comma but not the value.

Comment: Yah i tried it bro, but its not getting any value but the main submit button works here.

Comment: I'm testing this one MySQL 5.5, what's your version?  It should definitely not add comma when you specify one blank space.  What value does your `$values_keyword` have?  Can you do a `var_dump` of `$values_keyword`?

Comment: I think the problem is with posting the values bro, it is not getting the posted value, that is the problem.

Comment: Yah bro its not adding comma even.

Comment: @razor, I've updated my answer.  Make sure you use single quotes or double quotes around array index when you access them, e.g. `if(isset($_POST['keyword_submit_add'])){` and not `if(isset($_POST[keyword_submit_add])){`.  You have this in several places.

Comment: I already change that bro, but its getting only the last id, how to resolve that.

Comment: See my answer before the update.  The last id is probably because you have update outside of the while loop.

Comment: That unknown column is $values_keyword.

Comment: Need to post the id also in the form like this

Comment: if(isset($_POST['keyword_submit_add'])){
             
             
             $id_new = $_POST['id_new'];
             $get_keyword = $row_keyword_sql['keywords'];
                     $values_keyword = $_POST['keywords_extra'];          $ds = mysql_query("UPDATE keyword SET keywords = CONCAT(keywords,',', '$values_keyword') WHERE id = '$id_new'") or die(mysql_error());
                                      }

Comment: Bro if it is a new entry then comma is in front how to remove that?